# Не работает align-items: center;

Tags: html, css, html5

Имеется код:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.title {
  width: 50%;
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 50%;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
  .item-icon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
    .item-iconize {
      display: block;
      mask-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25180.svg');
      mask-size: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
    }
  .item-text {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  }
```

Почему .item {align-items: center;} не работает? Должно быть выравнивание по вертикали.

https://jsfiddle.net/bo8bry51/

Comment: Интересует решение на flexbox-ах, а не костыль в виде display: table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

При  `flex-direction: column;`   используйте    `justify-content: center;`

**flex-direction** – направление главной оси.

**align-items** – выравнивание по поперечной оси.

**justify-content** – выравнивание по главной оси.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Почитать про flex можете тут: [html5.by](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/)*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.title {
  width: 50%;
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 50%;
}
.item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    justify-content: center; /*Выравнивание по центру*/
}
  .item-icon {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
    .item-iconize {
      display: block;
      mask-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25180.svg');
      mask-size: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
    }
  .item-text {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-icon">
        <span class="item-iconize"></span>
      </div>
      <span class="item-text">Войти</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, не могли бы пожалуйста объяснить почему justify-content: center при flex-direction: column работает немного по-другому нежели при использовании без flex-direction? и получается что при использовании flex-direction: column выравнивание по центру align-items: center; нецелесообразно? Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: флекс дирекшн колумн меняет ось выравнивания с горизонтального на вертикальный, поэтому алин-итемс и джастифай-контент как бы "меняются" друг с другом свойствами (алин-селф тоже будет работать в горизонтальном направлении)

Comment: @Громидзе обновил ответ. Если внимательно посмотрите на изображение  и описание вопросы отпадут)

Comment: Если помог с ответам  будьте добры отметить как решение.

Comment: Большое спасибо всем кто ответил, решение от Даниила помогло!