# Как сверстать также?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите, как сверстать также кнопку и то что под ней, используя флексбокс, без position: absolute
нужно чтобы кнопка была по центру страницы, а начало строки ниже равнялось по левой стороне кнопки.

Comment: Какие у Вас возникли проблемы с этим?

Comment: Наверное большие,если упоминается absolute...

Comment: @Александр может тогда подскажите, если все так просто ?

Comment: Разметку и стили свои добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @Александр мне нужно это в контексте конкретного блока, а не всей страницы, дизайн не важен
моя верстка вообще не на html в этом случае

Comment: в codePen зайди поищи, похожий дизайн и код сюда, а так выглядит вот задание верстайте

Comment: @Vadim https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KepQbQ

Comment: @marates уже лучше осталось не много поверстать

Comment: а чем `position: absolute` не подходит? насколько я вижу тут по другому вообще никак

Answer (score 4):

Свойство **[justify-content](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746950/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-align-items-center/746951#746951)** - отвечает за расположение элементов по горизонтали.

```css
p{
 margin: 0;
}
.column{
 padding: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 10px;
}

.block{
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 15px;
}

.oneBlock{
 display: inline-block;
}

input{
 display: block;
 padding: 5px;
}
.inputBlock{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.button{
 border: 1px solid #333333;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
}
.button___block__img {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.button___block{
 display: flex;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.text__botoom {
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}
.text__botoom{
 font-size: 12px;
}
.text__button{
 text-align: center;
}

.button___block__img img{
  max-width:20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="block">
  <div class="inputBlock">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="buttonBlock">
   <div class="button"><p class="text__button">Sign Up</p></div>

   <div class="button___block">
    <p class="text__botoom">or sign up using</p>
    <div class="button___block__img">
     <img src="https://www.e-monsite.com/medias/images/integrer-fb.png" alt="">
     <img src="https://cdn131.picsart.com/265831648017212.png?r1024x1024" alt="">
     <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-2169/24/social_media_social_media_logo_google_plus-128.png" alt="">
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Нужно сделать что-то типа такого:

```css
.social {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="buttons_row"></div>
  <div class="buttons_row">
    <div class="social">
      <div class="social__text"></div>
      <div class="social__buttons"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот хорошее руководство по [flexbox](https://tuhub.ru/posts/flexbox-complete-guide), в котором можно посмотреть как вертикально выравнивать элементы.